# Vectorised between: datatable R

Tags: r, data.table, vectorization, between

I have a hard time to understand the "`Vectorised between`" example in `data.table` packages document `V1.10.4`?

```
X = data.table(a=1:5, b=6:10, c=c(5:1))
> X
   a  b c
1: 1  6 5
2: 2  7 4
3: 3  8 3
4: 4  9 2
5: 5 10 1

# NEW feature in v1.9.8, vectorised between
> X[c %between% list(a,b)]
   a b c
1: 1 6 5
2: 2 7 4
3: 3 8 3

X[between(c, a, b)] # same as above
```

Can someone please explain it to me how dose it work? why only `5,4,3` from `c` was selected?  Thanks.

Comment: In row 4, `2` is not between `4` and `9`....`between(c=2,a=4,b=9)`. `between` uses `>=` and `<=` (rather than `>` and `<`). That's why in row `3`, it returns `3` (since its `TRUE`)

Comment: @ChiPak Thanks a lot very clear now! :)

Comment: @ChiPak Might wanna turn that into an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*-----As posted in comments----*

In *row 4*, `2` is not between `4` and `9`....`between(c=2,a=4,b=9)`.

`between` uses `>=` and `<=` (rather than `>` and `<`). That's why in *row 3*, it returns `3` (since its `TRUE`)